Is pex in danger of damage if near a gas fireplace?
Any thoughts/concerns with Pex-A near gas fireplace? We have a gas fireplace in the corner of the living room. The bathroom backs up to the one wall and pex is approximately 10-12” from metal fireplace flue. I’ve read pex can become brittle from heat exposure, so I’m a little worried.
I believe it’s a zero clearance unit, as it was installed with paper-faced insulation touching it. However, I can’t confirm model information to verify. Utilizing Uponor Pex-A which says 200F max temp.

What is between the flue pipe and the pex? How hot does it get at the location of the pex when the fireplace is burning? Hot enough to burn you or not that hot?

The manufacturer of the PEX should have a data sheet for their product; one would expect it to list a maximum ambient temperature.

I'm not an expert in destructive testing of pipe, but here are some thoughts.

Max temp ratings are typically due to strength reduction at higher temperatures. In other words, 200° is as hot of fluid the pipe can contain at the stated pressure rating. It's not an indication of what will destroy the material.

A zero-clearance fireplace should never get hot enough to damage nearby materials unless it's being abused. My experience leads me to expect no hotter than about 150° F on the outer surface.

Pipe containing a fluid (water) really can't get much hotter than the temperature of the water. Heat applied to the outside would conduct into the water and limit the local heating of the pipe. So unless you find yourself with boiling water emerging from wherever that pipe leads, you have no real concern.

A quick search suggests that pex may melt at around 266° F (130° C). If you had empty pipes adjacent to the fireplace, that's the range of temp you'd have to see for things to get squishy.

Gas fireplaces are typically very controlled. I can load up my wood-burning unit and get things crazy hot. If your gas unit is installed and operating normally, you'd probably only see temperatures slightly warm to the touch on the outside.


